# Monitoring Content Change, Page Length not Consistent

Tags: php

I am trying to monitor the content of a page (to see if it changes over time).
For this purpose I have put together a small script that will compare the length of the content of the page to earlier stored text.

Script is as follows;

```
     <?
        function get_url_contents($url){
                $crl = curl_init();
                $timeout = 0;
                curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
                curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
                $ret = curl_exec($crl);
                curl_close($crl);
                return $ret;
        }
        $url = "X.php"; //The url to test against
        $ret = get_url_contents($url); //$ret contains the result

        $file = file_get_contents('../Y.txt'); //The text file where the ENTIRE content is saved
        if(strlen($file) == strlen($ret)) { //Compares string length
            echo "content is same";
        }
        else {
        echo "content not same";
        $fp = fopen('../Y.txt', 'w');
        fwrite($fp, $ret);
        fclose($fp);
        }
    ?>
```

I then try to compare the string length in a small table together with the % change.

```
            <table border="1">
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Guideline Master Page</th>
                <th scope="col">In File #</th>
                <th scope="col">% Change</th>
                <th scope="col">Current #</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><? echo $url; ?></td>
                <td><? echo strlen($file); ?></td>
                <td><? echo round((((strlen($ret) - strlen($file)) / strlen($file)) * 100),2); ?></td>
                <td><? echo strlen($ret); ?></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
```

When I actually make a change in page "X.php", on refresh the table will tell me the exact amount of characters I changed.

However, when I change nothing at all to either "X.php" or "Y.txt", the results keep changing, as an example:

(Refresh #) - (Current strlen of Page X.php) - (strlen of Y.txt)

1. 32885 - 32885
2. 32885 - 32894
3. 32894 - 32894
4. 32855 - 32894
5. 32894 - 32885
6. 32885 - 32894

Can anybody tell me where these changes originate from? The page that is being tested contains no changing elements for as far as I know.